# Codedeploy agent "The security token included in the request is invalid"

Tags: amazon-web-services

Today our CodeDeploy setup started failing for one of the instances with the following error:

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
>   failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
>   deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
>   experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

Upon checking /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log on both servers, one of them has the following error:

`2017-07-13 15:45:57 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(10192)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 400 0.013838 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:088736878764:instance/xxxx") Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException The security token included in the request is invalid.`

`2017-07-13 15:45:57 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(10192)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Cannot reach InstanceService: Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException - The security token included in the request is invalid.`

How would one go about fixing this? I'm not sure what to start with.
The only change on this server was to set `:max_revisions: 2` in codedeployagent.yml, restart codedeploy-agent and then delete (due to disk space constraints) an old revisions folder in /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/ which was dated to 2016.

I remember that manually deleting revisions (the ones starting with d-xxx) from an **active** revisions folder (the ones with the long hash id name) causes a big problem to CodeDeploy and the only solution is to recreate the deployment application. But this cannot be the case here, can it?

Comment: Check that the server's time is correct. Being even a few minutes off will cause this, IIRC.

Comment: Good point, however time seems correct. ntp is running too.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the same q to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=794706#794706, I'll leave this one here just in case it pops up on google.

It wasn't working because I had a set of credentials configured in ~/.aws and for whatever reason it started interfering with CodeDeploy, even if this configuration has been in place for over 2 years and it worked just fine.